# using requirejs to load npm packages

Tags: javascript, npm, requirejs

i want to use this code in run in html, how could i use require.js to do this

`const monerojs = require("monero-javascript");`

the following doesnt work i get "Script error for "monero-javascript""

```
requirejs(["monero-javascript"], function(monerojs) {

    main();
    async function main() {

    let walletKeys = await monerojs.createWalletKeys({networkType: "stagenet", language: "English"});
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Require.JS is for loading [AMD modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition).

Node.js modules are either [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (which use `import` and `export`) or [CommonJS modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) (which use `require` and `module.exports`).

Even though both AMD and CommonJS modules use a function named `require` they are, in general, **not compatible**. (It is possible to write a module so that it meets the requirements of both AMD and CommonJS but this isn't too common).

If you want to use Node.js modules in the browser then use a [bundler](https://medium.com/@gimenete/how-javascript-bundlers-work-1fc0d0caf2da) like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) (but note that they cannot provide APIs that are specific to Node.js, such as the `fs` module for reading and writing to and from the file system).

Comment: Just to clarify. Some libraries are both compatible with CommonJS and AMD. They detect the AMD via checking whether `define.amd` is defined and whether it is `true`. Most of libraries which I used were compatible so I could used them via RequireJS.