# Load npm packages using require.js

Tags: javascript, npm, requirejs

*Note: I have already found this SO question that appears to be a duplicate, but the answer does not seem to be correct: [using requirejs to load npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677607/using-requirejs-to-load-npm-packages)*

If I understand the require.js documentation [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) (second paragraph) correctly it should be possible to include npm packages without any special configurations. It even essentially says "don't touch anything and it should work".

All I should have to do is install require.js via npm and in my html file call the main script via require.js:
`<script data-main="js/main" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>`

Now I have this module in require.js format that does stuff that requires the mat4 from glMatrix (installed via npm):

```
define(["gl-matrix/mat4"], function(mat4) {
    return function() {
        //...
        const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
        //...
    }
});
```

But when I run it I get an error like: `GET file:///X:/projname/js/gl-matrix/mat4.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` which to me very much looks like it tries to use the normal js folder where the main script is, rather than making any attempt at loading any node packages.

Does anyone know if there is anything else I have to configure for it to also read npm packages?

Comment: If the npm package is not AMD-compatible, you can use tools like browserify, webpack, or rollup to bundle and convert the package to AMD format. This way, RequireJS can use the bundled package.